# A condition that an L_1 function is a characteristic of an atom

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\sigma,\mu)$ be a measure space with atoms, and consider $L_1(\mu)$.

For $f\in L_1(\mu)$ with $\Vert f\Vert_1=1$, if there not exists measurable subsets $A, B$ of $X$ with $A\cup B=X$ such that $\int_A|f|>0$ and $\int_B|f|>0$, is it true that $f=\frac{1}{\mu(F)}\chi_F$, where $F$ is an atom of $\mu$?

Comment: What if $f$ is identically zero?

Comment: a corrected the condition

Comment: I think you might need to allow that $f$ is a multiple of $\chi_F$, and require that $A$ and $B$ be in $\sigma$.

Comment: OK, what if $f = 2\chi_F$ where $\mu(F) = \frac 12$?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I edited, thanks.